# How to manage multiple roles using polymorphic association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I am using devise for authentication and finding a way to get out of this.

Can I explore same design user having multiple roles ?. So that he can login as Teacher or Parent both?. Basically he can switch accounts like multiple roles.

```
class User < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :loginable, polymorphic: true
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord
  has_one :user, as: :loginable
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord
  has_one :user, as: :loginable
end


for eg: loginable_type: "Parent", loginable_id: 123
```

I want to find a way to change above fields, if user is logging in as 'Teacher' and its ID.

Comment: what exactly you want to do

Comment: I want same user can login as 'Teacher' or 'Parent'. It is like switching roles.

Comment: Are you looking for a feature like "alias login" from admin side?

Comment: Not exactly but every user...bcoz one parent can be teacher also....so i have different mechanism for Parent and different for Teacher....

Answer (score 2):

You can add a polymorphic `has_many` relationship:

```
class CreateUserRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_roles do |t|
      t.integer :role_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string  :role_type # stores the class of role
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :user_roles, [:role_id, :role_type]
  end
end

class AddActiveRoleToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :user_roles do |t|
      t.integer :active_role_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord
   has_many :roles, polymorphic: true
   has_one :active_role, polymorphic: true


   def has_role? role_name
     self.roles.where(role_type: role_name).any?
   end
end
```

Comment: So i had to remove my loginable polymorphic association to make it work?

Comment: Thanks maxcal, your solution had given great idea to work with. It showed me way. Still looking for better solution.  +1